# Updating UITableViewCell subview's frame has no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a custom (subclassed) UITableViewCell which contains a few UILabels, a UIButton, and a NSBlock as properties. This subclass is called `ExploreCell`. Two of the properties are UILabels and are named `waitLabel` and `lastUpdateLabel` respectively.

When the contents of `lastUpdateLabel` is nil or is is blank i.e. `@""`, I need to move the `waitLabel` vertically down (on the Y axis) 10 pixels. I am doing this by checking some objects in an `NSDictionary` as shown in the following code which I have put in the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
CGRect frame = cell.waitLabel.frame;

if ([[venue allKeys] containsObject:@"wait_times"] && ([[venue objectForKey:@"wait_times"] count] > 0)) {

    frame.origin.y = 43;

}

else {
    frame.origin.y = 53;
}

[cell.waitLabel setFrame:frame];
```

However, this code intermittently works, and having tried to call `-setNeedsLayout`, still does not work. By intermittently, I mean that after scrolling a few times, one or two of the cells that match the criteria to move the cell's origin down 10 pixels, actually have their `waitLabel`'s frame changed.

Please can you tell me why this is occurring, and how it can be fixed.

Comment: Where did you put that code?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @rdelmar I haven't added any code to deal with auto-layout, however, I am using IB to design the cell's interface, so it's possible - my project is targeted at >= 6.0

Comment: If you didn't explicitly turn it off, then it's on. This could be the problem. With auto layout, you should make an outlet to a constraint to the top (or bottom) of the cell and change the constant of that constraint in code rather than setting frames.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks, that works perfectly - add it as an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a problem with auto layout. If you didn't explicitly turn it off, then it's on. You should make an outlet to a constraint to the top (or bottom) of the cell and change the constant of that constraint in code rather than setting frames. According to the WWDC 2012 videos, you shouldn't have any setFrame: messages in your code if you're using auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running

```
[CATransaction flush];
[CATransaction begin];
```

on main thread after updating those values?

Comment: That doesn't work, and I don't want to be using a hacky attempt at getting around this issue.

Comment: Oh, I have just seen where you do this. Just can't know why it does not work there. Reading fast thought it was something about performing actions on the wrong thread.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use [tableView beginUpdates]  +  [tableView endUpdates] when you change layout in any of your cells and want them to be seen immediately.

```
-(void)someMethod
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    // your code:
    CGRect frame = cell.waitLabel.frame;

    if ([[venue allKeys] containsObject:@"wait_times"] && ([[venue objectForKey:@"wait_times"] count] > 0)) 
    {

        frame.origin.y = 43;

    }
    else {
        frame.origin.y = 53;
    }
    [cell.waitLabel setFrame:frame];

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Make sure that [tableView beginUpdates] and [tableView endUpdates] always come together.

Comment: That's the incorrect usage of the -beginUpdates and -endUpdates methods. They are specifically for managing batch inserts, updates, and deletes of rows.

Comment: @max_ I had the same feature in my cells, where I had 3 labels and 2 of them were shifted and faded depending on some boolean value. I added beginUpdates and endUpdates to my code and it worked. Maybe it is because you have a custom UITableViewCell