# UIView not moving when i change origin

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, position, transform

trying to move a `UIImage` and a `UILabel` via the frame property however, no change is seen. Here's the code for the `UIImage` code:

```
- (void) switchVisualArrangement
{    
    CGRect temp = self.pic.frame;
    NSLog(@"pic: x coord before %f", self.pic.frame.origin.x);
    temp.origin.x = 0;
    self.pic.frame = temp;
    NSLog(@"pic: x coord after %f", self.pic.frame.origin.x);
}
```

The x pos of the x coord is 12, and then set to zero afterward.

Here's the output from NSLog:

```
2014-02-13 14:23:04.200 ImageList[1410:70b] pic: x coord before 12.000000
2014-02-13 14:23:04.201 ImageList[1410:70b] pic: x coord after 0.000000
2014-02-13 14:23:04.212 ImageList[1410:70b] pic: x coord before 12.000000
2014-02-13 14:23:04.212 ImageList[1410:70b] pic: x coord after 0.000000
```

as you can see there are two `NSLog` however 4 output lines, could you explain this as well.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *nibArray= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuViewTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

        [self switchVisualArrangement];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `switchVisualArrangement` from in your code? Please add some more code.

Comment: coz you might be creating two cells

Comment: You are loading cell from XIB and then resetting `frame` of its subviews, instead why not modify it in the XIB itself? Also seems like you are creating 2 cells hence the 2 set of `NSLog`'s

Comment: And about what change you want to see. May be the change is there but you are interpreting it in wrong way

Comment: @Amar i don't want to modify it in xib, because i need to give the .h to another developer who should have the choice of the view arrangement in the cell

Comment: UITableViewCell is create new if it can't reuse so you see two same result because it init other cell

Comment: @InderKumarRathore i want to see the change on screen, i don't know wot u mean by interpreting it in the wrong way...

Comment: Are you using auto layout to fix position of cell's subviews?

Comment: Try changing `switchVisualArrangement` to `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Do you want to animate it ??

Comment: @Amar; you solved the main problem, i unclicked the auto layout and now i can move stuff around, but i can't tick you coz you're a comment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating UITableViewCell subview's frame has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535054/updating-uitableviewcell-subviews-frame-has-no-effect)

Comment: @lost I have posted the link to original question which I referred to suggest you about auto layout. You can up vote the answer to that question.